# Submit Best time to the new scene unity3d

Tags: timer, unity-game-engine

It's my timer that counts time. Is it possible when the game gets to the new scene automatically insert the previous scene's best time? what code should i insert in the new scene to expose the best time?

```
/**
 * TIMER (JAVASCRIPT)
 * Copyright (c) gameDev7
 *
 * This is an HH:MM:SS count down/up timer
 * Includes functions for pausing timer
 *
 * TIP: Search where to place your functions
 * 1. Press Cntrl/Cmd + F
 * 2a. Type UP for count up timer (CAPS)
 * 2b. Type DOWN for count down timer (CAPS)
 * 3. Check Match whole word only
 * 4. Check Match case
 * 5. Click Find Next
 */

/// INPUT VARIABLES
var timerStyle:GUIStyle;
var countdown:boolean = false; //switches between countdown and countup

var hours:float = 0f;
var minutes:float = 1f;
var seconds:float = 30f;

var printDebug:boolean = false; //for debugging purposes

/// CALCULATION VARIABLES
private var pauseTimer:boolean = false;

private var timer:float = 0f;
private var hrs:float = 0f;
private var min:float = 0f;
private var sec:float = 0f;

/// DISPLAY VARIABLES
private var strHours:String = "00";
private var strMinutes:String = "00";
private var strSeconds:String = "00";

private var strHrs:String = "00";
private var strMin:String = "00";
private var strSec:String = "00";

private var message:String = "Timing...";

// Use this for initialization
//end start

// Update is called once per frame
function Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyUp("j")) {
        if(pauseTimer) {
            pauseTimer = false;
        } else {
            pauseTimer = true;
        }//end if
        if(printDebug) print("TimerJS - Paused: " + pauseTimer);
    }//end if

    if(pauseTimer) {
        message = "Timer paused";
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    } else {
        //message = "Timer resumed";
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }//end if

    if(seconds > 59) {
        message = "Seconds must be less than 59!";
        return;
    } else if (minutes > 59) {
        message = "Minutes must be less than 59!";
    } else {
        FindTimer();
    }//end if
}//end update

/* TIMER FUNCTIONS */
//Checks which Timer has been initiated
function FindTimer() {
    if(!countdown) {
        CountUp();
    } else 
    {
        CountDown();
    }//end if
}//end FindTimer

//Timer starts at 00:00:00 and counts up until reaches Time limit
function CountUp() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= 1f) {
        sec++;
        timer = 0f;
    }//end if

    if(sec >= 60) {
        min++;
        sec = 0f;
    }//end if

    if(min >= 60) {
        hrs++;
        min = 0f;
    }//end if

    if(sec >= seconds && min >= minutes && hrs >= hours) {
        sec = seconds;
        min = minutes;
        hrs = hours;
        message = "Time limit reached!";
        if(printDebug) print("TimerJS - Out of time!");
        ///----- TODO: UP -----\\\
    }//end if
}//end countUp

//Timer starts at specified time and counts down until it reaches 00:00:00
function CountDown() {
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer <= -1f) {
        sec--;
        timer = 0f;
    }//end if

    if(hrs <= 0f) {
        hrs = 0f;
    }//end if       

    if(min <= 0f) {
        hrs--;
        min = 59f;
    }//end if

    if(sec <= 0f) {
        min--;
        sec = 59f;
    }//end if

    if(sec <= 0 && min <= 0 && hrs <= 0) {
        sec = 0;
        min = 0;
        hrs = 0;
        message = "Time's Up!";
        if(printDebug) print("TimerJS - Out of time!");
        ///----- TODO: DOWN -----\\\
    }//end if
}//end countDown

function FormatTimer () {
    if(sec < 10) {
        strSec = "0" + sec.ToString();
    } else {
        strSec = sec.ToString();
    }//end if

    if(min < 10) {
        strMin = "0" + min.ToString();
    } else {
        strMin = min.ToString();
    }//end if

    if(hrs < 10) {
        strHrs = "0" + hrs.ToString();
    } else {
        strHrs = hrs.ToString();
    }//end if

    if(seconds < 10) {
        strSeconds = "0" + seconds.ToString();
    } else {
        strSeconds = seconds.ToString();
    }//end if

    if(minutes < 10) {
        strMinutes = "0" + minutes.ToString();
    } else {
        strMinutes = minutes.ToString();
    }//end if

    if(hours < 10) {
        strHours = "0" + hours.ToString();
    } else {
        strHours = hours.ToString();
    }//end if
}//end formatTimer

/* DISPLAY TIMER */
function OnGUI () {

    FormatTimer();
    if(!countdown) {        
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/4-155,Screen.height/3-10,200,90), strHrs + ":" + strMin + ":" + strSec + "", timerStyle);
    } //end if
}//end onGui

/* GETTERS & SETTERS */
public function GetPaused() { return pauseTimer; }
public function SetPaused(val:boolean) { pauseTimer = val; }

public function GetSec() { return sec; }
public function GetMin() { return min; }
public function GetHrs() { return hrs; }

public function GetMessage() { return message; }
public function SetMessage(val:String) { message = val; }
```

Comment: Can you abbreviate your code to what is necessary to reproduce the error? ALso what do you mean by "previous scene's best time"?

Answer (score 0):

Save your best time as a static variable in your `Timer` script (or whatever you have named it): `static var bestTime = 01:32:12`.

You can then access it globally from any other script (such as one used on a different scene) as: `Timer.bestTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the time as a static variable which will make it available across scenes. Alternatively you could use DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject) to preserve the game object that contains that script which means the game object and all the values of the components attached to it will retain their values. Be careful of using the second approach because if you go back to the scene that originally had the object, you will have duplicates. I believe the best solution in this case would be to just use a static variable and use it across all scenes.